# csvtojson node.js (combine two codes)

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

How to combine these two codes, so it doesn't just covert csv to Json (first code), but also save this as an json array in an extra file?(second code)
this (first) code converts csv file to json array:

```
const fs = require("fs");

let fileReadStream = fs.createReadStream("myCsvFile.csv");
let invalidLineCount = 0;

const csvtojson = require("csvtojson");
csvtojson({ "delimiter": ";", "fork": true })
.preFileLine((fileLineString, lineIdx)=> {
    let invalidLinePattern = /^['"].*[^"'];/;
    if (invalidLinePattern.test(fileLineString)) {
        console.log(`Line #${lineIdx + 1} is invalid, skipping:`, fileLineString);
        fileLineString = "";
        invalidLineCount++;
    }
    return fileLineString
})
.fromStream(fileReadStream) 
.subscribe((dataObj) => { 
    console.log(dataObj);
// I added the second code hier, but it wirtes the last object of the array (because of the loop?)
}    
});
```

and this (second) code saves the json array to an external file:

```
fs.writeFile('example.json', JSON.stringify(dataObj, null, 4);
```

The quistion is how to put the second codes into the first code (combine them)?

Comment: The first one converts CSV to JSON, but where's your JSON output? I assume it's `dataObj`? So what about just copying/pasting the second code in the first one?

Comment: I copied the second code here: .subscribe((dataObj)=>, subscribe works like a loop and the the array in the created json file is just the last object in the array of loop.

Comment: Hmmmm indeed, I had a look at the documentation, and it looks like the subscription triggers on every CSV line parsed, so `dataObj` is only a chunk of data. Maybe you need to manually add this chunk to an object? It's really weird that the library doesn't output the whole result automatically o_O

Comment: @JeremyThille, any Idia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.on('done',(error)=>{ ... })` method. ([csvtojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson)). Push the data into a variable in `subscribe` method and write the data as JSON in `.on('done')`. (test was successful).

Check it out:

```
let fileReadStream = fs.createReadStream("username-password.csv");
let invalidLineCount = 0;
let data = []

csvtojson({ "delimiter": ";", "fork": true })
  .preFileLine((fileLineString, lineIdx)=> {
    let invalidLinePattern = /^['"].*[^"'];/;
    if (invalidLinePattern.test(fileLineString)) {
        console.log(`Line #${lineIdx + 1} is invalid, skipping:`, fileLineString);
        fileLineString = "";
        invalidLineCount++;
    }
    return fileLineString
  })
  .fromStream(fileReadStream) 
  .subscribe((dataObj) => {
    // console.log(dataObj)
    data.push(dataObj)
  })
  .on('done',(error)=>{
    fs.writeFileSync('example.json', JSON.stringify(data, null, 4))
  })
```

Comment: please edith your answer, so it might help others :)

Comment: Done! I ma deleting all comments

Comment: I want to upload my project (nodejs project) online, do you know how to to run this code automatically by opining a specific page on my website?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are able to change the library but I would definitely recommend Papaparse for this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/papaparse

Your code would then look something like this:

```
const fs = require('fs'), papa = require('papaparse');
  var readFile = fs.createReadStream(file);
        papa.parse(readFile, {
            complete: function (results, file) {
                fs.writeFile('example.json', JSON.stringifiy(results.data), function (err) {
                  if(err) console.log(err);
                  // callback etc
                })
            }
        });
```